# JQuery function not working on initial trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

So I have a button that triggers a jquery function. In this function, an AJAX call is made (depending on certain factors) that appends div 'XYZ' somewhere in the doc. After this is done, I want div XYZ to popup with the leanModal bootstrap characteristics.

Here is the triggered function:

```
$(document).on("click", ".view_order", function(){
 //…stuff...
 var filled = $(this).attr("data-filled");
 if(filled == 0){
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'post', 
        data: {action: 'ABC123', var1: var1},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(popup){
           //div XYZ is created and appended.
        }
    })
 }
 // Now I call a function that mimics the bootstrap leanModal function (tailored to work   
 // without a selector)
 $.leanModalNoSelector({
    top : 200,
    overlay : 0.6,
    closeButton : ".modal_close"
}, $(this));
```

});

Here is a somewhat abbreviated area of code from leanModalNoSelector:

```
        var defaults={
                . . . . . . . . etc. . . . . . 
        };
        // this creates the grey background overlay:
        var overlay=. . . . . ;
        $("body").append(overlay);

        options=$.extend(defaults,options);
        return this.each(function(){
            var o=options;
            $(this).click(function(e){
                // Getting the href attribute of the original, clicked element (which points to div XYZ)
                var modal_id=$(this).attr("href");
                $("#lean_overlay").click(function(){
                    close_modal(modal_id)
                });
                $(o.closeButton).click(function(){
                    close_modal(modal_id)
                    });
                    // dimensions of the div XYZ set here
                     . . . . .etc. . . . . . . 
                    $("#lean_overlay").css({
                       //dealing with the overlay some more….
                    });
                    $("#lean_overlay").fadeTo(200,o.overlay);
                    $(modal_id).css({
                        "display":"block","position":"fixed",.. . . . . . .etc. . . .
                    });
                    $(modal_id).fadeTo(200,1);e.preventDefault()
                })
            });
        function close_modal(modal_id){
                 … … … … … … …
            })
        }
    }
```

My problem is that this works perfectly--the second time it is clicked. The first time the trigger element is clicked, the new div is created, but the leanModal function does nothing at all. If I click it a second time, however, the leanModal function works fine.

My question is why it doesn't work after the first click….thanks for any help in advance, guys.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @turbo2oh-Can't remember! I'm sorry…But I'll post if something jogs my memory :/

Answer (score 0):

Because your modal function is calling before the ajax success callback. You have two options to solve this proble:

1. Call the model function from inside the ajax success callback after div xyx appended.
2. Set the ajax config async property false, by default it is true.

   example:

```
     $.ajax({ 
            type: 'post', 
            data: {action: 'ABC123', var1: var1},
            dataType: 'json',
            async:false,
            success: function(popup){
               //div XYZ is created and appended.
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add async parameter and set it to false on your ajax:

```
   $(document).on("click", ".view_order", function(){
     //…stuff...
     var filled = $(this).attr("data-filled");
     if(filled == 0){
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'post', 
            data: {action: 'ABC123', var1: var1},
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function(popup){
               //div XYZ is created and appended.
            }
        })
     }
     // Now I call a function that mimics the bootstrap leanModal function (tailored to work   
     // without a selector)
     $.leanModalNoSelector({
        top : 200,
        overlay : 0.6,
        closeButton : ".modal_close"
    }, $(this));
```